# Why don't cell phones pick up music in phone calls?

Tags: acoustics, electronics, perception

Why is it that a listener on a cell phone cannot hear music on the other end?  For example, the source phone is located either in a car with music being played, or is at a concert.

The listener hears some notes, but for the most part the music is garbled and rarely is distinguishable what is being played.

I figured it has something to do with distortion, the size of the pickup mic, or the range of the pickup mic, but don't know.

Comment: [Your brain has the ability to become noise-canceling](https://www.google.com/amp/s/nypost.com/2018/09/13/your-brain-has-the-ability-to-become-noise-canceling/amp/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't you hear music well over a telephone line?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104281/)

Comment: I think this question belongs on another SE.  There is the obvious bandwidth thing (telephones traditionally had 2-4 kHz of bandwidth which is too small), but mobile phones do pretty hairy stuff with noise cancelling and general cleverness: they're not just some naive bandwidh-limited channel for audio at all.  So to understand what's going on you need to understand the processing they're doing, which would perhaps be at home on [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) but I'm not sure.

Comment: See also [Why can't person on other side hear music playing in my phone during a call](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191379/) on Android Enthusiasts SE